# ¿Cómo obtener una imagen Drawable mediante su ruta en Android?

Tags: android

Me refiero a retornar una variable `Drawable` que almacene una imagen pero cargarla mediante su ubicación en la carpeta `/drawable` donde se encuentre dentro del mismo proyecto.

Algo así:

```
Drawable imagen = getDrawable("imagen.png"); //Es ejemplo, esto no existe.
```

y después agregarla a un `ImageView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias formas de obtener la imagen almacenada dentro de `/drawable` .

La forma más común (Usar `ContextCompat`, para evitar el método obsoleto `getDrawable()`)

```
Drawable image  = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.androide);
```

---

también puedes usar el URI para obtener la ruta de la imagen dentro de `/drawable`:

```
 String uri = "@drawable/androide"; 
 int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());
 Drawable imagen = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), imageResource);
```

---

Pero la opción más sencilla, simplemente usar **[setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int))**, definiendo el id del recurso.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.androide);
```

Con las 3 opciones obtienes el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Usando este esquema:

```
Drawable imagen =  ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.+++);
```

Con ese método puedes obtener el Drawable, reemplaza los **+++** por el nombre de tu drawable

Usando una **URI**

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(tuUri);
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, tuUri.toString());
```

Comment: Amigo me refiero a buscar la imagen por medio de un String no por su id, osea si se puede buscar mediante el String de su ruta, como en el ImageIcon de java.

Comment: entonces usa `InputStream` :)

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo probare!

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que quieres obtener la imagen que selecciono el usuario.
Te anexo dos metodos, el primero es el que detona el abrir galeria, y el segundo es el como la respuesta una ves que ya la selecciono.

```
    public void abrirGaleria(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Seleccione una imagen"),
            SELECT_FILE);


}


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    Uri selectedImageUri = null;
    Uri selectedImage;

    String filePath = null;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_FILE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String selectedPath=selectedImage.getPath();
                if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {

                    if (selectedPath != null) {
                        InputStream imageStream = null;
                        try {
                            imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                    selectedImage);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Transformamos la URI de la imagen a inputStream y este a un Bitmap
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                        // Ponemos nuestro bitmap en un ImageView que tengamos en la vista
                        //ImageView mImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);

                        //mImg.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        imagenCaratula.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        imagenCargada = true;

                        caratula = ImagenUtil.getStringToImageBitmap(bmp);
                        Log.i("Caratula byte string",caratula);

                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case RESP_TOMAR_FOTO:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String selectedPath=selectedImage.getPath();

                if (selectedPath != null) {
                    InputStream imageStream = null;
                    try {
                        imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                                selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Transformamos la URI de la imagen a inputStream y este a un Bitmap
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                    // Ponemos nuestro bitmap en un ImageView que tengamos en la vista
                    //ImageView mImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);

                    //mImg.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    imagenCaratula.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    imagenCargada = true;

                    caratula = ImagenUtil.getStringToImageBitmap(bmp);
                    Log.i("Caratula byte string",caratula);

                }

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Eso te podría dar una idea. Ten en cuenta que este código es dentro de un Fragment, si lo tienes en un Activity cambiaria un poco , quitarías getActivity(). y lo que no sea necesario hacer implícito en un Activity.

Saludos